# Use of Plain JavaScript in angular5

Tags: javascript, angular, coding-style

Use of Plain JavaScript ( syntax like `getDocumentById`) in ***angular5*** project is good coding practice or not , or Should we use `ElementRef` , `TemplateRef` , `ContainerRef` for referring the `DOM` elements instead of Plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

> It's not encouraged to use the DOM element manipulation directly .
>   [This](https://medium.com/@kmathy/angular-manipulate-properly-the-dom-with-renderer-16a756508cba) blog explains why it should be avoided

With Angular 6 last update by google they have started moving towards [shadow dom](http://darylduckmanton.com/shadow-dom/) and dom hierarchy tree it would help dev community to not worrying about actual dom elements manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Use the framework, don't go direct to the DOM (which is what you mean by "plain JavaScript") unless you have no other choice. (Or don't use a framework at all.)

But note the warning in the [`ElementRef` docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef):

> Permitting direct access to the DOM can make your application more vulnerable to XSS attacks. Carefully review any use of `ElementRef` in your code. For more detail, see the [Security Guide](http://g.co/ng/security).

If you can avoid using `ElementRef` (without going direct to the DOM), that's probably best.